# How to get an old transaction from brownie

Tags: python, python-3.x, ethereum, solidity, brownie

I'm new at brownie and got stuck with this doubt.

Is there any way to call an old `tx` and get the event?

I'm working on a testnet and ganache-local.

Example:

```
tx = contract.createCollectible({"from": get_account(wallet=1)})
```

If I run again the code, it will create a new `tx` object.

Comment: I'm not sure however here is a great video about events with brownie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w18c9HLEuBs